# How to modify a file under src/python and run it without rebuilding in gem5?

Tags: gem5

If you modify a file under `src/python`, then a rebuild is necessary, unlike modifications to `configs/`

That makes making changes under that directory very painful, since even the clean rebuild takes several seconds.

Is there a way to avoid the rebuild?

Answer (score 1):

**`M5_OVERRIDE_PY_SOURCE=true`**

If you export that environment variable for the run, and gem5 uses the Python source code directly.

This likely exists because by default, gem5 packs up Python object files inside the `gem5.opt` binary so allows users to run it without changing their `PYTHON_PATH`.

How `M5_OVERRIDE_PY_SOURCE` works [is described here at 252dd80](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#m5-override-py-source).

Tested on: https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5/+/91295ff980c17efb3ad013b9636017b58e49c071