# gem5 simulation parameters do not change after editing Python files

Tags: gem5

I want to set some parameters for ARM CPU in O3 model so I edit O3CPU.py file in gem5/build/ARM/cpu/o3 directory but after running simulation I saw that changes do not affected in config.ini file in gem5/m5out directory!

Does any one know why it does not change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run with the `M5_OVERRIDE_PY_SOURCE=true` variable exported as mentioned at: [How to modify a file under src/python and run it without rebuilding in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312070/how-to-modify-a-file-under-src-python-and-run-it-without-rebuilding-in-gem5)

If that doesn't work, what is the gem5 version, full gem5 CLI and exact property you are trying to change?

Comment: that`s it! Thanks