# How do I avoid "fatal: Out of memory, please increase size of physical memory." in Gem5?

Tags: gem5

It looks like I can edit a config file to increase the physical memory being considered. Which config file is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Editing Options.py and changing the default "--mem-size" value there and then recompiling will be enough.

Comment: There should be no need to recompile BTW since this is a config script. And for m5 lib python stuff see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312070/how-to-modify-a-file-under-src-python-and-run-it-without-rebuilding-in-gem5/52312071#52312071